# convert data frame of numbers to single vector

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a data frame:

```
a=data.frame(matrix(1:30,ncol=5,byrow=1))
```

is there a way to extract the original vector (1:30) from the data frame as it exists?

I tried `unlist(a)`, but it was ordered by columns, and not row.

```
1 7 13 19 25 2 8 14 20 26...
```

`unlist(a, byrow=TRUE)` does not work. There must be an efficient way to do this that I am missing, any suggestions

Comment: You can use `c(t(a))`

Comment: There is an error in the code to create the data.frame. The first ) should be omitted.

Comment: @Ronak thanks. As an aside, how do questions get flagged as duplicates? I did not see this question when I searched

Comment: updated orig question

Comment: @alex If anybody knows that this question has been asked before they can find that question and flag it as duplicate. Finding that question is sometimes not that easy as you need to know exactly which search terms will lead you to the exact post. In this case I knew this question existed so I marked it as duplicate of the original question.